# Does Google penalise for "local" keyword stuffing?

Tags: seo, local-seo, keyword-stuffing

I want to optimise a site for local SEO on a website I'm working on, and some advice I've come across suggests putting local keywords everywhere you can.
i.e. content, headers, title, alt text, URL...

Currently it is in the content and the page title. How much can I get away with?

I know this is only one aspect of local SEO, but it seems like one which could be effective, if not penalised.

Comment: Just wrote content that makes sense for users. Catering to search engines is a recipe for failure. Users first. Everything just naturally follows. That's *not* a coincidence.

Comment: @JohnConde is perfectly right! Do not do this!! You will see a lot of SEO B.S. out on the web. Who pays for the bad advice? You! Localization will happen if you place the name, address, phone number (NAP) with schema.org mark-up on your site. The best places to put this is on the About or Contact page. You can also put it in the site header or footer. Just do not be obnoxious. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks guys! I come at this as a recently qualified inexperienced software developer, with a strong background in languages and writing. I've done a lot of reading and thinking, and the natural approach is exactly the one I've been taking, intuitive almost. I didn't build the site, a friend did, but I've done the rest.

Comment: Question: Would it be a good idea to use the localbusiness schema to add @type local business, as well as the address? Currently address is on there, but I've used the structured data testing tool, and only Organisation and website have been specified. The address has not been added to the site using structured data.

Comment: @jewfro If you have another question, open another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the local keyword everywhere, Google will most probably consider this as keyword stuffing. Don't take this risk!

The only important question is: **is your keyword important for users?**

If the answer is yes for a specific spot (content, `<title>`, `alt` attribute, etc.), put it, otherwise, don't.